# Is it possible to convert flutter code to figma design?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, figma

I've done converting figma to flutter code and i'm familiar with that , but now for some reason i have to convert some flutter code to figma design, any solutions for how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could make a web build from the old DOM renderer and then save the html and use one of the HTML->Figma converters that exist lol

Answer (score 0):

To use, simply select layer(s) you want to export, click "Export", then run the Flutter Export plugin and select "Export PNG". After reviewing the preview, you can save a ZIP file containing the exported layers in PNG format at 1x, 1.5x, 2x, 3x, and 4x, ready to drop into your Flutter project.

Note:- i have read this on website so i am not sure please try it and let me known

Comment: thanks for ur response , but this is figma to flutter ! 
what i want is converting flutter code to figma design.